# Can an S3 bucket generate its own object key names?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I'm configuring the Amazon API Gateway as a proxy for an S3 bucket. Ideally, I'd like the client to be able to POST a file to a bucket, have S3 assign it a file name, and then return that name in the response. I don't want to give the client the ability to specify the file name. Is this possible? The documentation for setting up the proxy doesn't mention POST at all, and other POST examples I've found still require the client to specify the key name.

Answer (score 2):

No, auto file name generation isn't supported in S3.

Answer (score 2):

S3 can't assign the name, but in the API gateway mapping template you could use any data from the $context object to construct a name.

e.g. $context.requestId would create a unique key name for your S3 key.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. How big is the request ID? Is it likely to be unique over long spans of time?

Answer (score 1):

If you went through Lambda you could insert any custom logic you wanted, including generating the file name of course. The Lambda function could then return the file name through and you could map it to your API Gateway response.

Comment: This isn't applicable in this case as Ishka s using AWS gateway as only a proxy.

Comment: I considered this, but there's a 6 MB limit on request size in Lambda, and I'd like to be able to upload files larger than that.