# How to create a unique random key name using API gateway as S3 proxy?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

If using API gateway as S3 proxy, I would like to generate the filenames / key-names as random strings.

Referring the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37621430/2410062), I understood that $context.requestId can be used to generate random keys. But, I am not able to use $context in the URL path parameters of integration request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok, found a way to solve this issue myself. 
`$context` can be used `context` in URL path parameters of integration request.
So for random keynames in S3, we can add `context.requestid` as key-name into the integration request of S3 proxy.

Comment: how did you appended the file extension to the request id like .jpg or .png?